# Appending column based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a new column and add the number 1 if multiple columns have nan values. However I keep encountering an error message when I run the code that I have written

```
df_test2['notsure']=np.where((df_test2[df_test2[['android','blackberry','chrome_os','linux',
                  'macintosh','tizen','windows_phone','windows',
                  'ipad','iphone','device_other']].isna().any(1)]),1,0)
```

Error Message:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is necessary filter by nested list:

```
cols = ['android','blackberry','chrome_os','linux',
        'macintosh','tizen','windows_phone','windows',
        'ipad','iphone','device_other']

df_test2['notsure'] = np.where(df_test2[cols].isna().any(1),1,0)
```

Alternative is convert boolean mask to integer for `True/False` to `1,0` mapping:

```
df_test2['notsure'] = df_test2[cols].isna().any(1).astype(int)
```